# "Winner team" vs. "winning team"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, compounds, present-participles

I would like to know which of the following fragments is correct when referring to somebody who is part of the team that won a championship:

> - Member of the winning team of...
> - Member of the winner team of...

Comment: This question is more suitable for [ell.se].

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that page existed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Winner* is uncommon as a modifier— Google Ngrams didn't turn up a single instance of *winner team* for me. We would say

> She is a member of the winning team, ABC.
>
> She is a member of the winning team of ABC.
>
> She is a member of ABC, the winners.

Answer (score 2):

Member of the winning team of...

Comment: Hi Ranjit, thanks for your answer. At ELU we tend to accept answers that can be substantiated by facts and are not just based on opinions. Could you support your answer with some sources please?